# Null Conditional operator inside SelectMany - still getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception, c#-6.0

## Accepted Answer @rob

I needed and a `.Where()` Clause/Operator

### Bonus points to @juharr for the direct answer to a misguided question

```
List<Guid> ExistingChildrenIDsFromParentsIcollectionJoinParentChildM2M =
        this.parent
        .SelectMany(
            p => p.joinParentChildM2M?
            .Select(jpc => jpc.ChildID)
            ?? new List<Guid> {Guid.Empty} //tried similar, but didn't understand the type needs of .SelectMany
            )
        .ToList();
```

### Original Question:

I'm about 10searches/40results in the hole and getting nowhere on this... TIA!

This statement is throwing NullReferenceException:
(p.joinParentChildM2M is sometimes initialized null sometimes not)

```
List<Guid> ExistingChildrenIDsFromParentsIcollectionJoinParentChildM2M =
        this.parent
        .SelectMany(
            p => p.joinParentChildM2M? //shouldn't this Null Conditional Operator break the chain?
            .Select(jpc => jpc.ChildID)
            )
        .ToList()
        ??
        GuidEmptyList();
```

I've tried:
 - moving the Coalesce ?? inside the SelectMany Parens()
 - adding DefaultIfEmpty (realizing empty is different than Null, but worth a shot)
 - adding another Null Conditional to `.Select(jpc => jpc?.ChildID)??Guid.Empty`

Here's the rest of the code:
(BTW: I'm fully open to other better ways to initilize by DAOParent class; but definitely want to learn proper Null Conditional syntax in this situation)

```
public class Parent
    {
    public Guid parentID {get; set;}
    //Other Properties...

    //one-way NavigationProperties
    public ICollection<JoinParentChildM2M> joinParentChildM2M { get; set; }
    }

public class JoinParentChildM2M
    {
    public Guid JoinID {get; set;}
    public Guid ParentID {get; set;}
    public Guid ChildID {get; set;}
    }

public class Child
    {
    public Guid childID {get; set;}
    //Other class Properties...

    //one-way NavigationProperties
    public ICollection<JoinParentChildM2M> joinParentChildM2M { get; set; }

    }


public class DAOParent
    {
    private dbContext _db;
    public IList<Parent> parents {get; set;}
    public IList<Child> children {get; set;}
    //Note: there is no IList<JoinParentChildM2M>, but parents contains an ICOllection<JoinParentChildM2M>
    //Other class Properties...

    public DAOParent( dbContext db , ParentIDList ParentIDList)
        {
        //set this._db, etc
        // this.parents will initialize null
        LoadAllChildrenOfParents()
        }

    public DAOParent( dbContext db , ParentIDList ParentIDList, DAOParent existingParents)
        {
        //set this.dbcontext, set this.parents to existingParents, etc
        // this.parents will initialize as non-empty objects
        LoadAllChildrenOfParents()
        }

    private void LoadAllChildrenOfParents()
        {

        //Before I grab new "Child" entities from the db 
        //I want to exclude existing ones already loaded in my POCO
        List<Guid> ExistingChildrenIDsFromParentsIcollectionJoinParentChildM2M =
                this.parent
                .SelectMany(
                    p => p.joinParentChildM2M? //shouldn't this Null Conditional Operator break the chain?
                    .Select(jpc => jpc.ChildID)
                    )
                .ToList()
                ??
                GuidEmptyList();
        }

    private List<Guid> GuidEmptyList()
        {
        List<Guid> g = new List<Guid> { Guid.Empty };
        return g;
        }


        //More code to finish initializing or updating DAOParent...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its not going to "break the chain" its just going to try and do a select on null.  Try splitting out your code. check for null where you are expecting possible nulls, and then don't perform any operations on null items.

Comment: You could do `p => p.joinParentChildM2M?.Select(jpc => jpc.ChildID) ?? Enumerable<Guid>.Empty()` because `SelectMany` expects an `IEnumerable` to flatten, so you can replace it with an empty one when it's `null`.  But really it's better to filter the `null`s first like Rob's answer.

Comment: @juharr thanks for explaining about IEnumerable. Played with the example syntax of `?? Enumerable<Guid>.Empty()` which threw another error of `CS0308 The non-generic type 'Enumerable' cannot be used with type arguments`.  But this worked: `?? new List<Guid> {Guid.Empty }`

Comment: @strategic.learner The correct syntax here would be `Enumerable.Empty<Guid>()` rather than `Enumerable<Guid>.Empty()`. Note that `new List<Guid> {Guid.Empty }` is very different - the latter creates a list with one guid (which is defaulted to all zeroes), while the other is an enumerable of Guids, which contains zero elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it's null, your query will end up being `.SelectMany(p => null)` which is probably *not* what you want. You should filter the collection before getting to the `SelectMany`.

Also, `ToList()` will never return `null`, so you don't need to provide a default. For example:

```
List<Guid> ExistingChildrenIDsFromParentsIcollectionJoinParentChildM2M =
    this.parent
    .Where(p => p.joinParentChildM2M != null)
    .SelectMany(p => p.joinParentChildM2M.Select(jpc => jpc.ChildID))
    .ToList();
```